# É possível criar e remover arquivos .properties do Android, pela própria aplicação?

Tags: android, arquivo

É possível criar e remover arquivos `.properties` do `Android`, pela própria aplicação? 
Ex: após criar uma anotação ele cria um arquivo `.properties` com o nome daquela anotação!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível criar ficheiros a partir da aplicação. Podes no entanto interagir com um ficheiro já existente. Para o efeito deverás:

1. Criar no teu projecto, no local desejado o ficheiro que vais utilizar a partir da aplicação.
2. Após o ficheiro criado, podes utilizar uma função do género da que apresento em baixo para guardar dados no mesmo:

   ```
   public void CreatePropertiesFile(Context context) {

     Properties prop = new Properties();
     String propertiesPath = context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/app.properties";

     try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(propertiesPath);
       prop.setProperty("HomeVersion", "0");
       prop.setProperty("DatePlaySquare", "0");
       prop.setProperty("CustomerID", "0");
       prop.setProperty("DeviceToken", "0");
       prop.setProperty("CurrentVersionMobile", "0");
       prop.setProperty("Domain", "Megazy");
       prop.setProperty("DownloadNewVersion","0");
       prop.store(out, null);
       out.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Failed to open app.properties file");
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

   Deverás adaptar a função às tuas necessidades, mas já ficas com uma ideia de como podes realizar a operação.

<sup>Isto é apenas um exemplo retirado [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395061/352449) no SOEN colocada pelo utilizar @user3113670.</sup>

<sup>Outro bom exemplo pode ser encontrado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222915/352449) também no SOEN colocada pelo utilizador @Javanator.</sup>

---

## A Saber

Em Android, quando falamos em guardar dados, falamos quase sempre em [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) mais especificamente [Preferências Partilhadas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Existe um tutorial muito bom sobre este assunto:

## [Android Essentials: Application Preferences](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-application-preferences--mobile-2914) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

<sup>Créditos desta informação para o utilizador @Rajesh [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222281/352449) no SOEN que evidenciou os links para a documentação e tutorial.</sup>